# Problem trying to archive Mac app in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, archive

I have created an app for iOS and Mac using Mac catalyst. I have been able to archive the app for testing on test flight, I know I can't use test flight for the Mac version and need to add the Mac ids to the developer account, which I have done, I can run the Mac app on my Mac that I built it with from Xcode, but when I try to archive it as my Mac, so I can distribute it I get 2 error on 2 pods. the error is:-

> Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

[image: image of error]

All pods are set to swift 5 I have updated all pods. It runs fine on Mac and phone, I can archive on phone this only happens when trying to archive Mac.

the pods I am getting error on are Badgable and Calendar Kit

Comment: Try clean build folder, try clean derived data and reinstall pods. It may be work.

Comment: I will give that a go

Comment: I tried that and get the same result

Comment: Can you threw out the pods and try archiving again. I know you have to uncomment a lot of Code, but give it a try. There must be a real error message anywhere.

Comment: @TonyMerritt did you find a fix for the issue?

Comment: @STerrier, I did here is the link, it’s a pain having to do this every time but it works, basically I got the header file and saved it on my desktop from this link, when I start archaic I g I have to add it in 2 folders that have the grpc https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20500#issuecomment-543241775